# does the surd $\sqrt[p-1]{p}$ for prime $p$ occur in any context?

Tags: exponential-function, prime-factorization, arithmetic-functions

for any prime $p \in \mathbb{N}$ use the corresponding symbol $q$ to denote the quantity $$q=p^{\frac1{p-1}}$$ and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define:
$$ Q_n= \prod_{p \le n} q
$$ empty products evaluate to unity.

let $\sigma_p(n)$ denote the sum of the digits in the $p$-ary notation for $n$ and define
$$n_{\sigma} =\prod_{p \le n} q^{\sigma_p(n)}
$$ then:
$$
 e^z  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n_{\sigma}\left(\frac{z}{Q_n}\right)^n \tag{1}$$

follows because 
$$ n! = \prod_{p \le n}p^{\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}}
$$
**Q.** the dissociation of the terms of the series using $n_{\sigma}$ and $Q_n$ seems superficially "natural" because of the way $Q_n$, like the variable $z$ is raised to the $n^{th}$ power in the corresponding term. however this procedure arteficially introduces a surd into the notation whose appearances alway cancel out. I wondered if there are other contexts in which $\sqrt[p-1]{p}$ appears ?

Comment: "Useful" is an opinion-based term... I do like the question, so I'm not voting to close, but if there was a different sort of phrasing, that would be great. ;)

Comment: i'll have a think how to rephrase it

Comment: These "unclear what you are asking" closings are getting to be increasingly odd.

Comment: As a mnemonic of anything all this seems rather definitely useless, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $p^{-1/(p-1)}$ is the radius of convergence of the so-called [$p$-adic exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_exponential_function) on $\Bbb C_p{}^\dagger$, and additionally sorta-kinda shows up in the formula for the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Examples) of a [cyclotomic field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field): $\Delta(\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q)=(in\prod_{p\mid n}\color{Blue}{p^{-1/(p-1)}})^{\varphi(n)}$. (In fact, I've been meaning to ask someone if these two appearances are connected in some algebro-geometric way or are only coincidental.)

${}^\dagger$Secretly this is the same example as yours.

Comment: thank you very much, that was exactly the kind of thing i was hoping someone might point out. since i am very un-knowledgeable about the concepts you mention, this will motivate me to delve a little deeper.

Comment: i have found a short introduction to p-adic analysis by Andrew Baker of Glasgow University (www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/​padicnotes.pdf), which seems very clearly written and eminently suitable for beginners. something about the definition seems reminiscent of the expansion of a meromorphic function near a pole as a Laurent series? is this a merely superficial resemblance, or does the analogy have some mileage in it?

Comment: The analogy definitely has mileage to it. In fact [these notes](http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/antchap5.pdf) *begins* its discussion of $p$-adics with a historical discussion of this motivation of Hensel's. Algebraically the same thing is going on: one completes the integers $\Bbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(p)$ to obtain the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$, and completes the polynomials $\Bbb C[X]$ at the prime $(X)$ to obtain formal power series $\Bbb C[[X]]$, and takes fraction fields to get the $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb Q_p$ and Laurent expansions $\Bbb C((X))$ respectively.